# Tic Tac Toe game - Array Not Saving Value?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a Tic Tac Toe game (with GUI) and I'm using a 2D array to determine the winner. I found out that the array does not save the previous value after the user clicks on a spot in the board.

so if board[0][0] is "X", the array is

```
[[X, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

after that if the user clicks on board[1][1], the array should be:

```
[[X, 2, 3], [4, X, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

but instead it is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, X, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Why does this happen?

this is the code:

```
private class Play implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        JButton src = (JButton) event.getSource();

        //create board
        String[][] board = {  {"1","2","3"},
                              {"4","5","6"},
                              {"7","8","9"}
                            };
        // who's turn?
        count++;
        if(count == 1 || count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 )
            letter = playerChoice;
        else if(count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
            letter = computerChoice;


        //player choice - show button
        if(src.equals(one)){
            one.setText(letter);
            one.setEnabled(false);
            board[0][0]= letter;
        }else if(src.equals(two)){
            two.setText(letter);
            two.setEnabled(false);
            board[0][1] = letter; 
        }else if(src.equals(three)){
            three.setText(letter);
            three.setEnabled(false);
            board[0][2] = letter;
        }else if(src.equals(four)){
            four.setText(letter);
            four.setEnabled(false);
            board[1][0] = letter;
        }else if(src.equals(five)){
            five.setText(letter);
            five.setEnabled(false);
            board[1][1] = letter;
        }else if(src.equals(six)){
            six.setText(letter);
            six.setEnabled(false);
            board[1][2] = letter;
        }else if(src.equals(seven)){
            seven.setText(letter);
            seven.setEnabled(false);
            board[2][0] = letter;
        }else if(src.equals(eight)){
            eight.setText(letter);
            eight.setEnabled(false);
            board[2][1] = letter;
        }else if(src.equals(nine)){
            nine.setText(letter);
            nine.setEnabled(false);
            board[2][2] = letter;
        }


        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board));
```

Comment: just a tip: to check for an even/odd number you can use the [modulo (`%`)](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273783-the-use-of-the-modulo-operator/) operator.

Comment: The question is, why should they?  You've created a local variable `board` inside the `actionPerformed` method, once the method exists, the variable no longer exists

Comment: @NoamHacker thanks for the tip! but i'm not checking for an odd/even number.. the program seems to be creating a new board(array) each time the player clicks instead of using one board(array)

Comment: @hamethyst What do you think `String[][] board = {  {"1","2","3"},{"4","5","6"},{"7","8","9"}};` is doing each time `actionPerformed` is called?

Comment: @MadProgrammer So after every action (user clicking on button), the old variable doesn't exist? Does this mean I should create a separate class for determining the winner?

Comment: @hamethyst you could use the even/odd checking to determine whose turn it is (right now your if loop works fine, but it would become quite messy if your game had more than 10 turns)

Comment: @hamethyst To my mind, a separate "model" would be useful, you would, however, need to make sure you are passing a reference of the model to the `Play` class, as it will probably need to be shared among multiple classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new, local variable, `board` each time `actionPerformed` is called...

```
private class Play implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton src = (JButton) event.getSource();

        //create board
        String[][] board = {{"1", "2", "3"},
                            {"4", "5", "6"},
                            {"7", "8", "9"}
                            };
        //...
```

This means the state is never saved between calls, it's re-created on each call.

Instead, `board` should be an instance field, for example...

```
private class Play implements ActionListener {

    private String[][] board = {{"1", "2", "3"},
                                {"4", "5", "6"},
                                {"7", "8", "9"}
                                };

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton src = (JButton) event.getSource();

        count++;
        if(count == 1 || count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9 )
            letter = playerChoice;
        else if(count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10)
            letter = computerChoice;
        //...
```

Comment: Ohh... wow.. I see my mistake now. That was dumb. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Welcome to the forest, watch out for the trees ;)